# firebase serve TypeError: glob pattern string required

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I currently have a deployed firebase application which I am now connecting with node to build a UI. I have previously deployed this application with firebase hosting and firebase realtime database and experienced no issues. Even when exactly replicating the sample code and directions from the video "Node.js apps on Firebase Hosting Crash Course - Firecasts" I am met with this error when attempting to call firebase serve from the command line. I am using Mac OSX. The error message is as follows:

```
i  functions: Preparing to emulate functions.
i  hosting: Serving hosting files from: public
✔  hosting: Local server: http://localhost:5000
✔  functions: helloWorld: http://localhost:5001/test-setup-5ae3a/us-central1/helloWorld
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Nov/2018:21:53:20 +0000] "GET /__/firebase/init.js HTTP/1.1" 200 - "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36"
TypeError: glob pattern string required
    at minimatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/minimatch/minimatch.js:94:11)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/superstatic/lib/middleware/rewrites.js:20:11
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/superstatic/lib/middleware/rewrites.js:33:17
    at _run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/superstatic/lib/activator.js:58:16)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/superstatic/lib/middleware/files.js:117:16
    at tryCatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:525:12)
    at invokeCallback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:538:13)
    at publish (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:508:7)
    at flush (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:2415:5)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
```

Here is my firebase.json:

```
{
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "sources": "/timestamp",
        "function": "app"
      }
    ],
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  },
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"
    ]
  }
}
```

Here is the index.js document within my functions folder:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
app.get('/timestamp', (request, responce) => {
  response.send(`${Date.now}`);
});

exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Comment: This is likely caused by something in your `firebase.json` file, so please include the minimal file that you can reproduce this with in your question. Also see [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this line:

```
exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

It should be:

```
exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```